# Writing a typescript compiler server

Tags: typescript, server

I'm thinking of simple web-server like what `tsc` does with files but compile everything into memory and serving clients via http. Typescript `npm` package comes with `tsserver.js`. This is some kind of server reading `JSON` from `stdin` and sending output to `stdout`. I can't find any docs regarding how to use it or what are its arguments.

My goal is simple. I start via `server --watch /myfolder --port:8000` And every client requesting a specific module e.g. `app` will be given a compiled version. No 100500 files created. No recompilation after each save. Incremental builds and cache can easily be supported.

What I should start for. I'm thinking of reading through `tsc` sources. But maybe there is something already. Typescript community is big and I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: You could just use Webpack/webpack-dev-server with the TypeScript loader.

Comment: Did you implement this service by any chance?

Comment: I am looking to do this too. There is tsc -w, but I only want to transpile one file, and I want to do it as fast as possible.

Comment: tsc seems to transpile all the files in your project upon a change to only one file, which is not what I want